# Huge memory Consumption (MVC 5 + EntityFramework 6.2.0 )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, autofac

I am having some concerns about my project using a lot of memory. I have configured my MVC 5 project with Entity Framework. I also use Autofac.

I locate my repository classes and service classes (which are in the same project) by doing:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(PlanRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

(And one similar for the services in that project. )

Now I can see when debugging that I initialize my _dbContext if it is not already and at the end I can see the dispose is called successfully. Upon launching the page, the memory usage is around 460 meg, and if I keep refreshing it goes slightly up and reaches to 500 meg and when I stop 10~15 mins later it drops back to roughly 460 meg.

Now I wanted to test something so I created a DBSet using the following model:

```
    public class Email
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       *[StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 32 characters")]*
       public string From { get; set; }
       public DateTime Sent { get; set; }
       public long Size { get; set; }
       public Boolean HasAttachment { get; set; }
     }
```

Two things to consider:

- I loaded the DBSet with **200,000 records** of the above Email
- Each record's **Subject** field is set to an string that is 2500 characters long

Now when I add a call to my method to just retrieve the data by:

```
var emails = _dbEmailService.GetAllEmails().AsQueryable();
```

My memory usage shoots up to **2Gig**...then every time I refresh it **adds up another 1 Gig**.

That is really bad isn't it? can I get some help please to figure out why? 
I have spent 1.5 days on this and very frustrated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this `var emails` live? And, are you storing that information somewhere, in a static list perhaps?

Comment: why you load 200000 records??? why you don't use paging?

Comment: And, is it your application or your (ms)sql instance which is consuming this much memory?

Comment: `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` is causing the issue here

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick replies.

Comment: Stefan, the emails var is being set in the Index controller that will later load the
view. 

And no that is just single call, just to test. I don't even use
it. Just trying to narrow down the problem.

Also that is something can't figure out. I can see the mem usage
in the diagnostics window of Visual Studio.

Comment: Hany, so eventual intention is to use paging. I am experimenting with
DevExpress components and they have a method called BindToEF
which will do the paging as long as you give it a Queryable method.
The doc is [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Mvc.CardViewExtension.BindToEF.method(25BOaw)).

Comment: amd, I was using InstancePerRequest initially. However, I need to initialise a 
Quartz scheduler, so I wouldn't be able to. After looking at the doco by Autofac
it looks like it is Ok to switch it out and use InstancePerLifeTimeScope. Please
see [here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#sharing-dependencies-across-apps-without-requests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. Hany your question made me go back and re-evaluate my paging approach. Initially I was getting the same problem with the paging, and that is why I started trying to retrieve all the records to see where the bottleneck is. But now after looking closer, I noticed that the paging wasn't really working because my Lambda was retrieving all the records, not just a IQueryable. Then there was a second problem where the request to DB was taking 3 seconds. This was due to lack of index on the ID column. Once I added it, everything started working as it should, with low memory footprint and very fast. Its amazing a few hours break from the screen can do. :)